# Use multiple reactive datasets to write to an excel workbook under downloadHandler shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

Good afternoon, thank you in advance for taking the time to read my question. In my Shiny app, I am trying to create a list of the reactive objects to write to a single excel workbook for the user to download. I was able to use parts of responses from other posts to replicate my issue and I get pretty close to a resolution. However, while the example below uses a list of dataframes, such as mtcars, iris, etc, I am trying to use reactive datasets, such as datasetInput1(), datasetInput2(), etc.

```
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        downloadButton("downloadExcelSheet", "Download Excel Workbook with Multiple Sheets")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) { 

        #### Write an Excel workbook with one sheet per dataframe ####
        output$downloadExcelSheet <- downloadHandler(
            filename = function() {
                "excelWorkbook.xlsx"
            },
            content = function(file) {
                # write workbook and first sheet
                write.xlsx(mtcars, file, sheetName = "mtcars", append = FALSE)

                # add other sheets for each dataframe
                listOtherFiles <- list(iris = iris, 
                                       airquality = airquality, 
                                       sleep = sleep)
                for(i in 1:length(listOtherFiles)) {
                    write.xlsx(listOtherFiles[i], file, 
                               sheetName = names(listOtherFiles)[i], append = TRUE)
                }
            }
        )
```

When I try to use these reactive objects in the example below, I am able to successfully download the data when there is just one dataset in the list. For example, the below works, but once I start adding more to the list listOtherFiles such as listOtherFiles <- list(datasetInput2(), datasetInput3()), I get an error.

```
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        downloadButton("downloadExcelSheet", "Download Excel Workbook with Multiple Sheets")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) { 

datasetInput1 <- reactive({

    data %>% 
      filter(sub_date == input$date, app_type == input$type)
})


datasetInput2 <- reactive({

    data2 %>% 
      filter(sub_date == input$date, app_type == input$type)
})

        output$downloadExcelSheet <- downloadHandler(
            filename = function() {
                "datasetOutput.xlsx"
            },
            content = function(file) {
                # write workbook and first sheet
                write.xlsx(datasetInput1(), file, sheetName = "dataset1", append = FALSE)

                # add other sheets for each dataframe
                listOtherFiles <- list(datasetInput2())

                for(i in 1:length(listOtherFiles)) {
                    write.xlsx(listOtherFiles[i], file, 
                               sheetName = names(listOtherFiles)[i], append = TRUE)
                }
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I can reproduce the problem. Here is my example below. This seems to work and uses two `reactive` expressions. Does it work for you?

If not, please edit your question and describe further. Perhaps include example data and `ui` with inputs to reproduce. What was your error?

```
library(xlsx)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    downloadButton("downloadExcelSheet", "Download Excel Workbook with Multiple Sheets")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { 

    datasetInput1 <- reactive({
      iris %>% 
        filter(Species == "setosa")
    })

    datasetInput2 <- reactive({
      iris %>% 
        filter(Species == "versicolor")
    })

    #### Write an Excel workbook with one sheet per dataframe ####
    output$downloadExcelSheet <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        "excelWorkbook.xlsx"
      },
      content = function(file) {
        # write workbook and first sheet
        write.xlsx(mtcars, file, sheetName = "mtcars", append = FALSE)

        # add other sheets for each dataframe
        listOtherFiles <- list(setosa = datasetInput1(), versicolor = datasetInput2())
        for(i in 1:length(listOtherFiles)) {
          write.xlsx(listOtherFiles[[i]], file, 
                     sheetName = names(listOtherFiles)[i], append = TRUE)
        }
      }
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: thank you Ben, this seemed to work! I copied a couple of things from your code that I didn't have such as naming the sheets, ie list(setosa =....) and the double brackets in the write.xlsx(listOtherFiles[[i]].... and those 2 edits collectively seemed to do it! thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

datasetInput1() is a reactive value not defined within the server logic. This needs to be assigned a value first or a function created to update values.

The following are some useful articles to understand shiny's reactive elements:

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/understanding-reactivity.html

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html

Comment: thanks for your response! I updated my code to include the reactive datasets I created. I have reviewed the resources you provided however my question is, can the reactive datsasets be stored in a list to write to an excel workbook?